# Change Applet Logo running in background (Cup of Cofee) to any choicable image?

Tags: java, applet

I want to change the logo running in background when applet is downloading and initiating.
Can i Change it to it to desired one?
I am attaching link here to clear better what i want to say.

[Applet Background Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce5qi.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/special_attributes.html#image

you can specify an image which is shown instead of the standard one.

Comment: Yes, Thank You very much. I found the solution and has implemented it.